# Basic circuit - valid pulldown

Tags: basic, short-circuit

I am trying to create a circuit with multiple 5V logical control lines pulled down with 10K resistor.

Is the below circuit the right answer? I can't help but feel like this will create a short across all logic lines.

[image]

Comment: where do you see the short across the logic lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pull-down resistors are correctly connected. They don't cause short circuits between the logic lines because the common connection is held at a fixed voltage. Any current that flows through one of the resistors will end up on the ground wire and return to the power supply.

Notes: 'V' for volt. 'k' for kilo. ('K' is for kelvin.)

Comment: @Equinox Don't forget that you can mark an answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: Isn't 10k too little for pull down resistors? You may see voltage falling when the line is high. I'd put at least 100k but I don't know the rest of the project so it's up to you.

Comment: @Fredled Picking what value to use for your pull-(up,down) resistors is a bit of an art; higher values slow switching.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying he made a mistake because I didn't see the entire project. But when the line turns off in high impedance state, it falls to 0V (or ground ref) pretty quickly even with values higher than 100k. And when the line will go high, a low value resistor to ground will act like a voltage divider. A pull up resistor slow down switching more because it resists against the current.